How to extract text from a CSS ::before pseudo-element using Selenium in Python?
I am trying to extract the text content from a ::before pseudo-element in an HTML document. I understand that traditional HTML parsers like BeautifulSoup cannot render CSS and thus cannot access pseudo-elements directly. Therefore, I am using Selenium to achieve this.
enter image description here
I want to get the text content of the ::before pseudo-element associated with the span element that has the class hs_kw11_configMs.
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('example.com')


# The class is different every time. The general pattern is "hs_kw/d/d_config/w/w"
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.hs_kw11_configMs')

before_content = driver.execute_script(
    "return window.getComputedStyle(arguments[0], '::before').getPropertyValue('content');",
    element
)

print(before_content.strip('"'))

driver.quit()

#Output: "content"
#Actual output: 


enter image description here
While this script runs without errors, I am not getting the expected text content from the ::before pseudo-element. Can anyone help me identify what I might be doing wrong or suggest a better approach to achieve this?
reference url: https://car.autohome.com.cn/config/spec/67034.html#pvareaid=3454541

Use a webdriverwait for element to be visible and then try using the .text method on it to get the content.  (Seems like that should work since it'll evaluate rendered text node.)  If not your current method seems correct, 'cept be careful of syntax around passing the element argument to the script.  This getComputedStyle will only read the property of the style... it won't confirm that it is visible.

for testing purpose i am usingthe script in the dev tool's console. I ran the script when the content is visible on page but it still does not work for me.
Here is the script I am using in console.
window.getComputedStyle($0, '::before').getPropertyValue('content');
$0 is currently selected element and I have confirmed the selected element is correct

have you tried with element.text? (in Selenium?)
